# How do I convert the frames of a GIF into PNGs using ffmpeg?

Tags: image, ffmpeg, png, gif

I have a `.gif` file on my file system and I want all of its frames to be saved as `.png` files. How can I do this with [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ffmpeg -i target.gif frame_%d.png`

This little command extracts frames from a GIF and saves them as PNGs named like this: `frame_0.png`.

- `-i` identifies the input (in this case, it's: `target.gif`).
- `%d` is a *placeholder* that'll be replaced by a numbers.

Turns out that `ffmpeg` does this frame extraction business for free. Thanks, `ffmpeg`!